# How can i get the value which is inside the HTML tag and bind it to the ts(component file) in aurelia

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, aurelia

I want to manipulate the text inside the paragraph and get it's context to the component where I can manipulate it. 
Basically I want to do this:

#### HTML file

```
<p bind="text"> Some text here </p>
```

#### Typescript file

```
export class Example{
  @bindable text;
  constructor() 
  {
    this.Function()
  }

    Function() {
     console.log(text) 
     //Here i want to be printed out Some text here
    }
}
```

I don't mind if the answer will be written in jQuery or in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to share more information. What does your component look like? Is this paragraph available for this component? Are you willing to manipulate with DOM directly, etc.

Comment: @DawidZbiński I edited it, hopefully i made it more clear. I want to know if its possible to bind the text which is inside the paragraph <p> in this case "Some text here" i want this to bind on the variable text. Then when Function() is called (in this case in the constructor) it will print out Some text here in the console.
Did i make it clear, do you understand the problem ?

Comment: - Do not call any Function() in constructor. Do calls in attached() or bind(). - in constructor - the content may not be accessible - this.text = ? undefined.

Answer (score 2):

the accepted answer is really **NOT** the way to go.
you should just do:

```
<template>
    <p>${text}</p>
</template>
```

1. binding to `innerhtml` without sanitization is dengarous.
2. extra and unnessesary code.
3. having notion of the `DOM` inside the `VM` is contradictive to the `MVVM` paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is **not correct**, even though it's working. See accepted answer for better integration and explanation.

I've never worked with ***aurelia*** before, but looking at [the documentation](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#element-content), this should do the trick:

Template:

```
<template>
    <p ref="myParagraph" innerhtml.bind="text"></p>
</template>
```

Component:

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    text = 'Example text';

    constructor() {
        this.exampleFunction();
    } 

    exampleFunction () {
        console.log(text);
        // text should be here
    }
}
```

If you need to read the text first (it's already set somewhere else, not in the component), you might need to read the value in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
    this.text = this.myParagraph.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: - Do not call exampleFunction() in constructor. Do calls in attached() or bind(). - in constructor - the content may not be accessible - this.text = ? undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to consider using custom attribute, or manipulating using `ref` - but still it may be bad practice (JQuery/Angular way) of manipulating DOM directly.

1. Do manipulation of DOM in bind(), attached() or in other methods of life cycle of the component, do not do it in constructor.
2. use `ref` attribute to access element within VM class.
3. use e.g. `MybindCustomAttribute` to define custom attribute `mybind` and write it in `mybind.js` file. Then the content of the attribute is achievable via `valueChanged()` method. Do not use `bind` as attribute name - as it can be confusing.

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from='./mybind'></require>
  <p ref="myparagraph" mybind="Add other text. ">Some text here. </p>
</template>
```

app.js, note that manipulateContent() adds some content within your the component:

```
export class App {
  constructor() { }
  attached() {
    this.mytext = this.myparagraph.innerHTML;
    this.manipulatecontent();
  }
  manipulatecontent() {
    this.mytext += 'Hello world.';
    this.myparagraph.innerHTML=this.mytext
  }
}
```

mybind.js, with custom attribute class per Aurelia convention. You access the value of the attribute in valueChanged() method:

```
export class MybindCustomAttribute {
      static inject = [Element];

      constructor(element){
        this.element = element;
      }

      valueChanged(newValue, oldValue){
        this.element.innerHTML += newValue;
      }
}
```

Fiddle it with GistRun at https://gist.run/?id=b712431087519a20d1a29c88906b7fe9